# How to deploy and devforce entityserver as console application with topshelf

Tags: devforce

We want to run our wpf client application in 3-tier mode using the entitymanager console with topshelf to test and run the entityserver locally.

We can find only documentation using the provided Tools ServerConsole.exe but we want to build the Console ourself.

Is it possible to build an entityserver with an console application and run it locally?

The documentation http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/deploy-console is not explaining, how to build the console yourselfe without the provided ServerConsole.exe.

Answer (score 0):

DevForce will host the `EntityServer` in three ways (well, four actually):

- via the ServerConsole.exe as a console application
- via the ServerService.exe as a Windows Service
- via IIS/ASP.NET
- The 4th option isn't really a hosted service, but whenever you run in 2-tier mode a local in-process EntityServer is used.

The hosted options all start at least two WCF services:  `EntityServiceHost` and `EntityServerHost`.  These are public sub-types of `System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost` and can be found in the IdeaBlade.EntityModel.Server assembly.  We don't provide documentation or guidance on how to use these.

If you can tell me more about your requirements maybe I can offer other alternatives.

Comment: We keep receiveing erros running the wpf applikation in n-tier mode.

We are using the visual studio template for wpf-ntier applications but as soon as we want to connect to the server tier, we receive some weard errors.

We have setup a vistual directory at http://localhost:8080/TestEntityService

Answer (score 0):

We keep receiveing erros running the wpf applikation in n-tier mode.

We have setup a vistual directory at http://localhost:8080/TestEntityService

We are using the visual studio template for wpf-ntier applications but as soon as we want to connect to the server tier, we receive some weard errors.

we can browse to the service using internet explorer: http://localhost:8080/TestEntityService/EntityServer.svc

but our wpf client is always throwing a very weard exception:

```
Sunrise.Shells.Lisp.vshost.exe Error: 0 : 2017-03-23 

10:29:12.6148|ERROR||Sunrise.Modules.Instruments.ViewModels.HostViewModel+<LoadInstruments>d__112 | MoveNext ==> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
InnerException:
Communications with the service 'EntityServer' using Uri of 'http://localhost:8080/TestEntityService/EntityServer.svc cannot be started.  See the internal exception for more information.
InnerException:
Type 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.Messages.Encoders.BinaryEncoders.InsertMessageBinaryEncoder`1+InsertFlags[TDocument]' cannot be exported as a schema type because it is an open generic type. You can only export a generic type if all its generic parameter types are actual types.
StackTrace:
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSet.EnsureTypeNotGeneric(Type type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XsdDataContractExporter.GetSchemaTypeName(Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.ValidateDataContractType(Type type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter..ctor(OperationDescription description, DataContractFormatAttribute dataContractFormatAttribute, DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerFactory)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.GetFormatter(OperationDescription operation, Boolean& formatRequest, Boolean& formatReply, Boolean isProxy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior.System.ServiceModel.Description.IOperationBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(OperationDescription description, ClientOperation proxy)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BindOperations(ContractDescription contract, ClientRuntime proxy, DispatchRuntime dispatch)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
   at System.ServiceModel.Description.DispatcherBuilder.BuildProxyBehavior(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, BindingParameterCollection& parameters)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelFactory.BuildChannelFactory(ServiceEndpoint serviceEndpoint, Boolean useActiveAutoClose)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.CreateFactory()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.OnOpening()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory.EnsureOpened()
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address, Uri via)
   at System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1.CreateChannel(EndpointAddress address)
   at IdeaBlade.EntityModel.WcfProxy`1.CreateProxyCore()
```

The Server does not have any reference to mongodb dll's but the client is not able to connect.

```
Type 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.WireProtocol.Messages.Encoders.BinaryEncoders.InsertMessageBinaryEncoder`1+InsertFlags[TDocument]'
```

Comment: This error is occurring on the client as the WCF proxy to the EntityServer is initialized.  During this initialization DF will probe for "known types", and it looks like a type in this MongoDB assembly is getting picked up.  This might happen if the type is referenced by one of your entity types, but without more information it's hard to say.  You can exclude the assembly from this initialization probing using IdeaBlade.Core.Composition.CompositionHost.SearchPatterns.Add("someassembly.dll");  See http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/discovery#HControllingdiscovery.

Comment: Hi Kim, is ripped out all mongodb references from the client and it is working. But of course we still need this mongodb connection on the client..  i will follow the documentation in order to control the composition searchpattern.